# How do I display the row count in a table as it paginates using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, pagination, html-table

I have this table where I got the pagination working. I have a select box with options to display 5, 25, 50, or 100 rows on a page. I also have first, previous, next, and last links for table pagination. How do I display a count of rows such as Viewing 6 - 10 of 25?

Here is the JSFiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/t5Kg6/

I tried this following code but it does not work:

```
var rowCount = $('#ClaimsList tbody tr').length;
                var numOfVisibleRows = $('tbody tr:visible').length;
                $('#viewRowCount').html('Viewing ' + numOfVisibleRows + ' of' + rowCount);
                $('#tablePagination_rowsPerPage').change(function(){
                    $('#viewRowCount').html('Viewing ' + numOfVisibleRows + ' of' + rowCount);
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want something like this:

```
function getCurrentRows(rowsPerPage, currPage, rowCount) {
    var from = (rowsPerPage * currPage) - rowsPerPage + 1;
    var to = (rowsPerPage * currPage) > rowCount ? rowCount : rowsPerPage * currPage;
    return "Viewing rows " + from + " to " + to + " of " + rowCount;
}
```

and call it (in your example) like this:

```
getCurrentRows($('#tablePagination_rowsPerPage').val(),
               $('#tablePagination_currPage').val(),
               $('#ClaimsList tbody tr').length);
```

Comment: I tried it and it did not work. I am trying to build off your example. The counter is not dynamically changing. It is staying at Viewing rows 1 to 5 of 179

Comment: @Mojaray2k: You'll need to hook it up to a `change` event for when the list is paged or the amount of rows-per-page is changed.

Comment: @Mojaray2k: `getCurrentRows` returns a string - you need to put that string somewhere on the page in order to see it. Something like `$('#myPlaceholder').html(getCurrentRows(...))` in your `change` handler will do it.

Comment: Hey Town that worked. But also a part of this algorithm are the first, prev, next, and last links. The row counter is not increasing or decreasing when they are click. For example 1 to 5 of 179 does not got to 6 to 10 of 179  What logic can I add? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Mojaray2k: See my first comment above - whenever anything happens that requires a refresh of the current rows (changing rows-per-page, moving backwards/forwards through pages) you'll need to call `getCurrentRows` and update the `#myPlaceholder` content.  Quickest way would probably be to give all buttons a class and then do `$('.myNewButtonClass').click(function() { ... getCurrentRows stuff ...});`

Comment: Should I put a click even on each of those links and run the same function? Oh I was on the right track I will put a click event to capture each of those links. Thanks Man. It has been a long day so forgive my brain deadness.

Comment: @Mojaray2k: Yeah, do that, but rather than one click handler for each button, if you assign a class to each of them you can add all the click handlers with one selector.

Comment: I got it implemented by adding one click handler by doing the following:   $('#tablePagination_paginater img').click(function(){
                        getCurrentRows($('#tablePagination_rowsPerPage').val(), $('#tablePagination_currPage').val(), $('#ClaimsList tbody tr').length);
                    });

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the values in variables, so for total count you query your database and save that. For the 6-10 you figure out how many are being displayed per page and times that by the page number -1, so on page 1 it would be 1 to ... And the ... Is where you use a counter variable for each item that is displayed on your page.

Comment: Only problem here is that he said he wanted to use jQuery.

Comment: True, but then I think the general logic could be applied there.

Comment: I'd remove the PHP reference from your answer, this has absolutely nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Well you know the page number (p) and the number of rows per page (r).

So you want Viewing (p-1)*r+1 to p*r of total.